Relation of automorphic representation and its constant term
Let $\pi$ be an irreducible non-cuspidal automorphic representation of a classical group $G$ defined over a number field $F$. Let $P$ be a maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$. Let $\pi'$ be the automorphic representation of G generated by the constant terms of elements in $\pi$ associated to $P$. Suppose that $\pi' \ne 0$ and consider $\pi'$ as a representation of $M$, the Levi subgroup of P.
Then it seems that $\pi$ is isomorphic to an irreducible constituent of the normalized induced representation of $\pi'$.
I have read some paper and it seems that the author uses this fact implicitly. But I don't know why it does.

The constant terms are 0 if $\pi$ is cuspidal.

@Kimball, Oh, I am sorry! $\pi$ is assumed non-cuspidal and $\pi'\ne0$.

What was the paper?

@LSpice, here is the link for the paper "https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/CRELLE.2007.023/html?srsltid=AfmBOoqYM0i_nOipygMZZPtXNWx6x6zivFDAv61JWImCt2lku5mTJM71". The point I am asking is p.204, -5 from the bottom. It says that if the theta lift of $\sigma$ a cuspidal automorphic representation of $Mp_{2n}$ to $SO(2n-2)$ is cuspidal, then its theta lift to $SO(2n)$ is locally isomorphic to almost everywhere its constant term associated to a maximal parabolic subgroup $P$ such that whose Levi subgroup $M$ is isomorphic to $GL_1 \times SO(2n-2)$. It may by applied only to this case.

OK, thanks.  Name of that paper: Jiang and Soudry - On the genericity of cuspidal automorphic forms of $\operatorname{SO}_{2n + 1}$.

Re, I don't know (although I do know that I would lend no more weight to it because ChatGPT said it).

@LSpice, I found that the condition 'locally isomorphic' in my original question is related to the special case considered in the paper. Hence, I modified the question appropriately, and I think it should hold from its local analogue of the Jacquet module.
